# How do I change RGB value without changing the Alpha channel?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

I would like to know how can I change color of RGBA image when alpha channel will be unchanged for each pixel. If I use Paint Box Tool it will set alpha channel for all pixels to constant value.

Look at picture:
[image: changing color of RGBA image in Photoshop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option somewhere on the tools pallet called 'preserve transparency' that should do exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The fast way to accomplish this, rather than using the Paint Bucket, is to use the keyboard shortcuts.

To fill with color while preserving transparency hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you fill using:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> or
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd>

I don't remember when I last used the Paint Bucket. It's been so long I'd forgotten it was there...

Comment: I don't think I've used that modifier before.  Good tip.

Answer (score 2):

Although not as slick as Alan's method, which I will be using after this, a general method is to lock layer transparency before fill, painting, filters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

All the current answers are probably better solutions in most cases, but in some cases you can also:

- Just apply a layer style to the color/gradient/pattern you want. Which I find slightly easier to make adjustments to—since you can adjust the color using the color picker dialog with a live preview, and layer styles also have other advantages (being saveable, easily transferred/copied, gradients hold up better when converting color profiles)
- Using a clipping/layer mask—this can be done in a few ways:

  1. Load the selection from the existing layer; then create a new fill layer (either a solid color, gradient or pattern).
  2. Or select the existing layer and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new layer, checking the `Use Previous Layer to Create Clipping Mask` option.
  3. Or just select the existing layer; hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, and then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
  4. Or you can create a layer mask by loading selection from the existing layer and then going to `Layer > Layer Mask > Reveal Selection`.

  It's a slightly more roundabout way to achieve the same general thing, but clipping/layer masks let you do some cool things sometimes, like just painting or pasting images into the layer and still preserve the alpha channel.