# How do I preserve transparency over a 'paste' operation in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

Basic situation:

I have an image with a *complex* alpha channel (ie. feathered, complex non-linear edges).

I have an image I want to overlay on top of the first image using a blend option like multiply or maybe screen.

...but I *must* preserve the EXACT alpha channel of first image.

Can I do this in photoshop?

If I paste the second image it creates a new layer, and the multiply, screen etc options overwrite the alpha values on the first image (layer 1).

Seems like there should be an easy way to do this?

I saw this question:
[How do I change RGB value without changing the Alpha channel?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/how-do-i-change-rgb-value-without-changing-the-alpha-channel)

...but messing around with the lock-alpha options didn't seem to do anything.

NB. The reason I mention the complex edges in the image is that the feature tool doesn't select the alpha channel correctly; simply select-using-magic on layer 1, goto layer 2, delete doesn't even remotely work.

Comment: I think what you're after will be possible and easy, using a clipping mask. Do you have some example images to work with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a clipping mask within Photoshop.

Option (mac) or Alt (Win) click between two layers. The Top layer will then be restricted to only displaying in areas where the bottom layer exists.

[image: Clipping Mask]