# Fill an area while keeping transparency

Tags: transparency, paint.net

In Paint.NET I'd like to change the color of an icon by using the fill tool, but I want to preserve the alpha-channel of the pixels. There's the [same question for Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/how-do-i-change-rgb-value-without-changing-the-alpha-channel), but I can't find a solution for Paint.NET.

**Before fill:**

[image: Pixels with alpha channel]

**After fill:**

[image: Pixels without alpha channel]

As you can see, the semi-transparent pixels lose their alpha-cannel value. Is there a way to achieve this in Paint.NET?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is something I was looking for as well.  The code was almost identical to the sample code of the [CodeLab Tutorial Part 1 - Simple](http://boltbait.com/pdn/CodeLab/help/tutorial.asp)   plugins walkthrough.  So after a couple minutes, there is now a simple plugin to do this job right from Paint.NET.

https://github.com/friedrickjoel/AlphaColor/raw/main/AlphaColor.dll

Comment: @Joel That's great if you are hosting it. I just cleaned the comments, thanks!

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you very much for this.  Easy and simple and exactly what I needed!!

Comment: This works awesome. For Paint.NET noobs like me, how to install plugins:
http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/1708-how-to-install-pluginsgeneral-plugin-troubleshooting-thread/

The plugin shows up under Effects > Color, and applies whatever the current primary color is while preserving Alpha values. Thanks Joel!

Comment: Just placing the dll in the Paint.Net\Effects folder and restarting Paint.Net was all that it required for me.  Thanks Joel!

Comment: Providing a DLL without knowing where it is coming from is a security issue however. Too bad the source code is not posted on GitHub.

Comment: Then just don’t download it.  This was 9 years ago.  Moved from Dropbox to GH to keep it alive for people who need it.  Source code is, as noted, almost 100% identical to the sample code for making a plug-in for Paint.NET except the alpha level parameter in the on of the methods.  You’re welcome to make your own code and DLL and I’ll gladly take my post down.

Answer (score 2):

As a developer, I just wrote a small C# program to perform this task for me:

```
public class Program
{
  public const string IMAGE = @"logo.png";

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Color targetColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 3, 143, 106);

    using (var image = Bitmap.FromFile(IMAGE))
    {
      using (var bmp = new Bitmap(image))
      {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
          for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
          {
            var alpha = bmp.GetPixel(x, y).A;
            bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(alpha, targetColor.R, targetColor.G, targetColor.B));
          }
        }

        bmp.Save("icon.png", ImageFormat.Png);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and failed to find a way to do this directly in Paint.NET 3.36.

You can't do it by filling a selection, as selections comprise whole pixels only, not alpha. The Tolerance setting on the Magic Wand tool just determines the colour threshold for selection of whole pixels.

Neither can you fake it with a "fill" layer above, as you can't use the original layer as a mask.

I think the closest thing you can do is use Adjustments > Curves to shift the hue of the pixels, but this is an indirect way of doing it, and it will be very difficult to hit a given target colour (although perhaps not impossible with a bit of maths).

However, you can render Mandelbrot and Julia fractals!

Comment: I played with the curves, but gave up on getting the exact color. Maybe I'll use Oil Painting instead :P